# EFCore AlterColumn MaxLength in Code First Migration

Tags: c#, database, ef-code-first

Using Visual Studio 2019 C#.

I'm very new to a code first development approach.

I've made a working ToDo.cs data model and ApplicationDbContext.cs.  I ran PM>add-migration to auto-generate the data migration below and then PM>database-update to commit the table to my SQL Server successfully.

```
FILENAME: 20200815211807_AddedToDoTable.cs


using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace BlazorApp.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class AddedToDoTable : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ToDoList",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 15, nullable: false),
                    Status = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    DueDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ToDoList", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "ToDoList");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to change the string length of the [Name] column from 15 to 25.  So, I created a new migration like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace BlazorApp.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class ChangeNameLength : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE ToDoList ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(25);");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But the Package Manager says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." And doesn't make any changes.

What am I doing wrong?  Can you help me understand this simple change?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the correct migration syntax:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
         name: "Name",
         table: "ToDoList",
         maxLength: 25);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem had to do with my usage of the Package Manager Console.

I started over using the same migration script and everything worked fine!

```
PM> add-migration "ChangedNameLength"
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Done.
PM>
```